# Django admin search for multi-word phrase with ^ and = operators

Tags: python, django

Assume a model admin has:

```
search_fields = ("^name", "=kind")
```

If `name` is `"Leonardo Da Vinci"`, it can be found using the query `Leon` or `Leonardo`, but not `Leonardo Da` or `Leonardo Da Vinci`. If `kind` is e.g. `"polymath genius"`, such a value cannot be found with any query. Ideally, one would be able to post `"multiple words" "Leonardo Da"` and get this record; but given how Django splits the query, it doesn't do what one might expect.

This problem was apparently raised 9 years ago in [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6933), and solved. Then Django got rewritten and apparently this got dropped somewhere.

Does anyone have an idea if this is possible? I'm probably thinking I'd need to override `ModelAdmin.get_search_results`... Anything more elegant?

Comment: no, this is standard way

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I could think of. I really don't like it because it looks like it may fail if Django is updated. It's a lot of copy-pasta to basically just change a single line (`for bit in search_term.split():`)

```
from django.utils.text import smart_split, unescape_string_literal
from django.db import models
from functools import reduce
import operator
from django.contrib.admin.utils import lookup_needs_distinct

class QuotedSearchModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
        """
        Returns a tuple containing a queryset to implement the search,
        and a boolean indicating if the results may contain duplicates.
        """
        # Apply keyword searches.
        def construct_search(field_name):
            if field_name.startswith('^'):
                return "%s__istartswith" % field_name[1:]
            elif field_name.startswith('='):
                return "%s__iexact" % field_name[1:]
            elif field_name.startswith('@'):
                return "%s__search" % field_name[1:]
            else:
                return "%s__icontains" % field_name

        # Group using quotes
        def unescape_string_literal_if_possible(bit):
            try:
                return unescape_string_literal(bit)
            except ValueError:
                return bit

        use_distinct = False
        search_fields = self.get_search_fields(request)
        if search_fields and search_term:
            orm_lookups = [construct_search(str(search_field))
                           for search_field in search_fields]
            search_term_list = [unescape_string_literal_if_possible(bit)
                                for bit in smart_split(search_term)]
            for bit in search_term_list:
                or_queries = [models.Q(**{orm_lookup: bit})
                              for orm_lookup in orm_lookups]
                queryset = queryset.filter(reduce(operator.or_, or_queries))
            if not use_distinct:
                for search_spec in orm_lookups:
                    if lookup_needs_distinct(self.opts, search_spec):
                        use_distinct = True
                        break

        return queryset, use_distinct
```